# What do the older X-series games offer not included in Albion Prelude

Tags: x-series

It was recommend to me to take a look at the X Series for a flight simulator with fighting and trading

X3:Terran Conflict with X3:Albion Prelude expansion is the latest.
How many hours of game play does it offer?
Do you need the previous games, Reunion and The Threat to understand the game?

X3: Reunion  is this even worth getting if you have X3:Terran Conflict?  Does one game handle better than the other in smoothness of play and UI controls?

x2: The Threat released in 2006 -- does it run on a i5 processor now a days?  Is there anything in this game that was good and not carried over to the  X3: Terran Conflict game

X: Tension and 
X: Beyond the Frontier released in 2010  -- Same questions as above

Thanks for the help

Comment: This Question comes down to a shopping recommendation which is off-topic according to the site policy: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/establishing-an-official-no-shopping-recommendation-policy

Comment: If that is the case then what about these two questions which encouraged me to ask the question.     http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246/is-portal-worth-getting        http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/972/ive-played-the-original-lego-indiana-jones-is-it-worth-getting-the-follow-up

Comment: @Mike Both of the linked questions are from two years ago.  We have since firmed up the rules for these types of questions.  Also, it's explicitly stated in the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) to not ask for shopping advice and recommendations.  I'd recommend you read it.

Comment: And still they received 10 upvotes vs -3 ... seems like the community likes these types of questions

Comment: Reformulated as "What do the older X-series games offer not included in Albion Prelude" I think this question _has_ a place here, as yx.'s answer indicates. It's just the current state "is it worth it" that sounds a bit too subjective

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question as per @Zommuter's question; as it stands, it's very subjective, and is not a good fit for Q&A.  Doing so would get my vote for re-opening the question.  And the body needs to be edited too; just changing the title doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: btw X3:AP is an addon to X3:TC, so you can't play AP without getting TC

Comment: modified the question to reflect that fact.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to answer only the concrete aspects of the question:

1. X3:Albion Prelude is the latest in the X series, it is built on top of X3: Terran Conflict and contains the latest advances in the gameplay as well as graphics.  From a gameplay perspective, there's no reason to play any older games in the series, just AP.
2. The X games will run fine on a i5 processor, but you will also need a graphics card to handle it.
3. The only reason to ever play the earlier games is for the story, which you can easily gleam from reading a wiki about them.

Comment: I feel Reunion's controls are vastly superior than TC and AP's. You can approximate R's controls in TC and AP, but not quite get there. If you haven't been exposed to the awesomeness of R's controls, though, it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you can run X3:TC then get that AND X3:AP. Both games are amazing and in-depth as any of the previous titles, plus the X3 series has advanced physics simulation.

However for me, X2:The Threat was the most immersive due to having first person cockpit view, which has since been removed, but there are several mods that add them back in.

Docking was also more fun in X2; more realistic in X3, but it was nice to actually see the inside of the stations on X2, even if you couldn't really explore them.