# Does Lego Indiana Jones 1 have any content that is not present in Lego Indiana Jones 2?

Tags: version-differences, lego-indiana-jones, lego-indiana-jones-2

Based on [Does Lego Indiana Jones 2 contain any new content compared to Lego Indiana Jones 1?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/972/ive-played-the-original-lego-indiana-jones-is-it-worth-getting-the-follow-up), Lego Indiana Jones 2 seems to outperform Lego Indiana Jones 1 in every respect. It has the same movies and the same levels from those movies, but it also has:

- more levels for each movie
- extra levels based on the newest movie
- the existing levels have been extended
- more characters
- more options in general
- ...

Am I missing something here? Does 1 have any content that is not present in 2? Or is all the content from 1 present in 2?

Comment: ...a different story, probably?

Comment: @frank 1 is movies 1 through 3. 2 is 1 through 3 with extra levels and also movie 4. My question is: does 1 have content that 2 does not have?

Comment: That sounds like an excellent question to ask, rather than asking if if it's worth it.

Comment: @Frank I based my question on the linked question, but I agree that I should have made it more clear. I edited my question to clarify my intent.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Already mentioned this to you in chat, but the linked question is really poorly written. Only reason it's probably gone so long without a rewrite is because of how old it is.

Comment: @Wipqozn The question wording might be poor, but the question itself has merit. Personally, I read the description in the Steam store page, which made me wonder about this question.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs IT does, whihc is why I took the time to rewrite it so it's more in line with how we suggested you phrase your question'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played both games (Thoroughly loved the first one, still play it now and then on my PSP), though it has been a while since I have played them.

From what I can remember, you are right - 2 has pretty much everything 1 has but more. Although, I found the first game's levels were much more direct in the puzzles and navigation then the second game, which I would say involved a lot more running around. Personally, I loved the levels in the first game much more than the second.

Pretty much the only difference I can remember is the levels (Oh, and similar to a lot of other lego games where you wander around in a special location to go to things like levels, character customisation, etc. you get to play around Barnett College). But since the levels vary so much from the second game, I highly reccomend getting it on top of the second one.